# angular service test fails to return required response

Tags: angularjs, json, unit-testing, http, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write tests for angular service using jasmine and karma. I have the following code for my service call:

```js
angular.module('omdb', [])
  .factory('myservice', MyService);
MyService.$inject = ['$http'];

function MyService($http) {
  var vm = this;
  var service = {};
  service.getData = function() {
    return $http.get('omdb/mydata.json').then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    });
  };
  return service;
};
```

I am tesitng it using the following file for spec as:

```js
describe('myservice', function() {
  var mockservicedata = [{
    "name": "value1",
    "id": "1"
  }, {
    "name": "value2",
    "id": "2"
  }, {
    "name": "value3",
    "id": "3"
  }];

  var myservice = {};
  beforeEach(module('omdb'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_myservice_) {
    myservice = _myservice_;
  }));

  it('should return search myservice data', function() {
    expect(myservice.getData()).toEqual(mockservicedata);
  });
});
```

which basically throws an error as:

```
Expected d({ $$state: Object({ status: 0 }) }) to equal [ Object({ name: 'value1', id: '1' }), Object({ name: 'value2', id: '2' }), Object({ name: 'value3', id: '3' }) ].

stack@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js:1482:17 
buildExpectationResult@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js:1452:14 
Env/expectationResultFactory@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js:583:18       
Spec.prototype.addExpectationResult@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js:324:29 addExpectationResult@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js:533:16
Expectation.prototype.wrapCompare/<@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js:1406:7 
@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/spec/omdb/myservice.spec.js:14:9 
attemptSync@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js:1789:9 
QueueRunner.prototype.run@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js:1777:9 QueueRunner.prototype.execute@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js:1762:5 
Env/queueRunnerFactory@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js:627:7 
Spec.prototype.execute@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js:353:5 executeNode/<.fn@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js:2360:32 attemptAsync@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js:1819:9 
QueueRunner.prototype.run@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js:1774:9 
QueueRunner.prototype.execute@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js:1762:5 
Env/queueRunnerFactory@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js:627:7 
executeNode/<.fn@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js:2345:13 attemptAsync@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js:1819:9 
QueueRunner.prototype.run@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js:1774:9 
QueueRunner.prototype.execute@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js:1762:5 
Env/queueRunnerFactory@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js:627:7 
TreeProcessor/this.execute@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js:2209:7 
Env/this.execute@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js:678:7 
window.onload@http://localhost:59239/movie-app/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/boot.js:110:5
```

I don't understand why it does not return data to the test. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `myservice.getData()` won't actually give you the data you're expecting.

Since your `getData` method from `MyService` relies on `$http`'s `get` method, you should be mocking it and then expecting that data returned.

So your test case should be like:

```js
describe('myservice', function() {
  var mockservicedata = [{
    "name": "value1",
    "id": "1"
  }, {
    "name": "value2",
    "id": "2"
  }, {
    "name": "value3",
    "id": "3"
  }];

  var myservice = {};
  beforeEach(module('omdb'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_myservice_, _$httpBackend_) {
    myservice = _myservice_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

    $httpBackend.when('GET', "omdb/mydata.json").respond({
      status: 200,
      data: mockservicedata
    });
  }));

  it('should return search myservice data', function() {
    var response = myservice.getData()
    response.then(function(response) {
      expect(response.data).toEqual(mockservicedata);
    });
    $httpBackend.flush();
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried running that. it gave me a 
 `ReferenceError: $httpBackend is not defined in http://localhost:59239/movie-app/spec/omdb/myservice.spec.js (line 14)`

how do I add it to my spec. do i need to include another file for running the test

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the part about getting the value from response. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

getData() will never return data instead it will return promise object.
If you want to test it then firstly you would have to mock the data for service then you can call it and match the result in the success handler.

Code is attached below:

```
describe('myservice', function() {
  var mockservicedata = [{
    "name": "value1",
    "id": "1"
  }, {
    "name": "value2",
    "id": "2"
  }, {
    "name": "value3",
    "id": "3"
  }];

  var myservice, httpBackend;
  beforeEach(module('omdb'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_myservice_, $httpBackend) {
    myservice = _myservice_;
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
  }));

  it('should return search myservice data', function() {
    httpBackend.when("GET", "omdb/mydata.json").respond(mockservicedata);

    var promise = myservice.getData();
    promise.then(function(response) {
       expect(response.data).toEqual(mockservicedata);
    });
    httpBackend.flush();
  });
});
```